# How to check for vertical win in Bingo

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

All the code is in the main method essentially.So i have printed a bingo board and i have to check for a vertical win only. At the end of the if statement in the main method i have put together a check but for some reason when i run the program i get an infinite loop. Could someone please explain to me why i'm wrong in detail or where the error is and how you would do it?

```
package bingo;

import static bingo.Bingo.gameCounter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Bingotake2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] card1 = new int[5][5];
        int[] random = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75};
        int x = 0, get = 0, gameCount = 0, gameCount2 = 0, county = 0;
        int[] columncounter = new int[5];
        boolean turn = true, gameOver = true;
        System.out.println("PLAYER 1'S CARD");
        cardPlayer1(card1);
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a positive integer to begin BINGO!/GO AGAIN");
            get = input.nextInt();
            if (get > 0) {

                List l = new ArrayList();
                for (int i : random) {
                    l.add(i);
                }

                Collections.shuffle(l);
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println(l.get(i));
                    x = i;
                }
                System.out.println(" ");

                firstPart(columncounter);
                for (int k = 0; k < card1.length; k++) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < card1[k].length; j++) {
                        county++;
                        if (card1[k][j] == x) {
                            columncounter[j]++;
                            System.out.println("PLAYER 1 CHECK AT " + card1[k][j]);
                        } else {
                            //System.out.println("else");
                            columncounter[j]=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int p = 0; p < columncounter.length; p++) {
                    if (columncounter[p] == 5) {
                        turn = false;
                        //System.exit (1);
                    }

                }
                //System.out.println(random);

            } else {
            }
        } while (turn == true);
        System.out.println("PLAYER 1 wins");
//        if (gameCount == 5) {
//            System.out.println("PLAYER 1 WINS");
//        } else {
//            System.out.println("PLAYER 2 WINS");
//        }

    }

    public static void cardPlayer1(int[][] card1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < card1.length; i++) {
            int a, b, c = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < card1[i].length; j++) {
                b = (15 * (j + 1));
                a = (int) ((b - (b - 14) + 1) * Math.random() + (b - 14));
                if (a != card1[0][j] && a != card1[1][j] && a != card1[2][j] && a != card1[3][j] && a != card1[4][j]) {
                    card1[i][j] = a;
                    System.out.print("|" + card1[i][j]);
                } else {
                    j--;
                }

            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] firstPart(int[] columncounter) {
        for (int m = 0; m < columncounter.length; m++) {
            columncounter[m] = 0;
        }
        return columncounter;
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'm sure you can think of a better way to get all the numbers from 1 to 75 without creating a constant array that lists them all.  Also, `(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` is the most pointless loop I've ever seen.  Why is this a loop?

Comment: its to only pick one number i know its pointless but its for my purpose of understanding why its there

Comment: I suggest you print out the value of `columncounter` after your double loop (i.e. just before `for (int p = 0...`.  Use something like `System.out.println("columncounter=" + Arrays.toString(columncounter));`.  You'll probably see that it's not what you think it is.